# Lotus Notes View Column Date Format

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have imported an excel file into a Lotus Notes database using LotusScript. One of the columns in my view (which displays the imported data) shows a date. If the year is greater than 2000, it is shown with 4 digits e.g. 2001. 
However if the year is less than 2000 the year is displayed with just 2 digits e.g. 99.
Does anybody know why this is?
The date is contained in a text field. The column uses the "Date / Time" style with "Show Only month, day and year". Display Time is not selected.

Comment: It's a text field? Have you tried using @TextToTime in the column formula?Or, since you imported it with a script, why aren't you importing it as a date item?

Comment: Yes, it is a text field. Using @TextToTime gives an error and no values are correctly displayed in the column. The value contained in the field is a time/date value. What I do not understand is why dates greater than 2000 are displayed with 4 digits and dates less than 2000 are displayed with 2 digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your column properties, look at the 4th tab (Advanced Format).  You say you have "Date/Time" selected, and "Display Date" selected.  Nex to that in the "Special" field, have you ticked "Show 4 digit year for 21st century"?  If so, 20th century dates will show with 2 digits, 21st century ones with 4.

I remember when this feature was added, and thinking how cool it was. God, I feel old!

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks a lot.